# Using a Timeout with a Search Function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to delay the execution of this function (which returns if there are no results), because I need to allow for time for a search query function to complete it's own delay while the user is typing. How could I wrap this function in a timeout? Would that work?

```
public get noResultsFound(): boolean
    {
        if (this.query && !this.hasResults) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not think it would work that way. How your search function look like? Could you post the code? I think you could make good use of `rxjs` on this type of scenario.

Comment: It just seems like putting the code in the callback function you supply to setTimeout would work. I just haven't been able to get it to work yet.